# Using Authlogic with a User model that isn't called "User"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I have an application that tracks people, but all those people are, possibly, users of the product. I'd rather have the model called Person (rather than User), but can't seem to figure out how to indicate to Authlogic that I'm using Person instead of User.

I'm sure it's somewhere obvious that I'm just not seeing, but I've been pouring over things for hours now and I'm giving up. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just add `acts_as_authentic` in the `Person` model, and everything should work just fine. If you face anything says `User` in the documentation, then just change them to `Person`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the [authenticate_with](http://rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/Session/Klass/Config%3aauthenticate_with=) method inside of your session class, like so:

```
class CaseWorker < ActiveRecord::Base 
 acts_as_authentic do |c| 
   c.session_class = 'Session' 
 end 
end 

class Session < Authlogic::Session::Base 
  authenticate_with CaseWorker 
end
```

The above code  was lifted from [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/authlogic/browse_thread/thread/cf4e3514c9129d91).

Answer (score 1):

The name of the model class is inferred from the name of the session class that you derive from Authlogic::Session::Base.

class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base goes with the Users model.

class PersonSession < Authlogic::Session::Base should bind up to your Person model.

At least, that is what worked for me after an hour of digging through Authlogic's poor documentation.